# AWS Lex always goes into Fallback intent

Tags: nlp, chatbot, amazon-lex

I am using AWS Lex as a POC and have created just 1 Intent (and the default fallback intent exists). It always returns the Fallback Intent for the questions I asked. The things I have tried are:

1. Input the same query as utterance
2. Reduce threshold to 0.1
3. Add slots to clarify

Somehow, the NLP model isn't learning anything. What's the best way to rectify this?

**PS**: I'm using the Basic AWS plan, but I don't think it should affect the NLP model trained by Lex

Comment: Your plan won't impact Lex's capabilities. Confirm that you've built the bot and that there were no errors. It's always good to ensure you have a few variations of utterances rather that just one.

Answer (score 0):

*This is based on Lex V1*

Like Reegz said, your AWS plan should not impact what Lex can do.
The first thing is to make sure you've clicked build after adding your utterances. You may also want to add a few more utterances for the same intent.

### If you are using a Lambda function with your Lex:

Make sure you have created a handler for your intent. A common way of structuring Lambda for Lex is to filter the incoming requests based on Intent name. Check to make sure you have this as forgetting to do so will cause your Lex to always go to fallback *(something I learned when I was first using Lex)*. An easy way to check this is to detach the Lambda from the intent temporarily. If the Lex returns the default `Intent <intentName> is ReadyForFulfillment:` or some other error after doing this, there is likely an issue with the Lambda handler.

Although I do not know how your Lex is structured, if you are using a Lambda, or what version of Lex you're using. If you're still looking for an answer, I might be able to help you better with this :)
However, I know this is an older question. If you already found a solution, please share it! It'll help someone in the future.